How can i make the result from fetch_revenue display on the table
<?php
// Database connection
$host = 'localhost'; // Change this as needed
$dbname = 'cms_db'; // Your database name
$username = 'root'; // Your database username
$password = ''; // Your database password

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}

// Fetch total revenue for each payment head
$query = "SELECT payment_head, SUM(amount) AS total_revenue FROM payment_data GROUP BY payment_head";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$revenue_data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Output the data in JSON format for AJAX
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($revenue_data);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Live Revenue Report</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Function to update revenue data
            function updateRevenueData() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'fetch_revenue.php', // The PHP script to fetch revenue data
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json', // Explicitly expect JSON data
                    success: function(data) {
                        let tableBody = $('#revenue-table');
                        tableBody.empty(); // Clear the existing data

                        data.forEach(row => {
                            let newRow = `<tr>
                                <td>${row.payment_head}</td>
                                <td>${row.total_revenue.toFixed(2)}</td>
                            </tr>`;
                            tableBody.append(newRow);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error("Error fetching revenue data:", error);
                        alert("An error occurred while fetching the revenue data. Please try again later."); // Notify the user
                    }
                });
            }

            // Update the data every 10 seconds
            setInterval(updateRevenueData, 10000);

            // Initial data fetch when the page loads
            updateRevenueData();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Live Revenue Report</h2>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Payment Head</th>
                <th>Total Revenue ($)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="revenue-table">
            <!-- Data will be populated here by AJAX -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>


I AM TRUING TO MAKE THE TABLE SISPLAY THE DATA FETCHED FROM THE FETCH_REVENUE.PHP
HERE ISMY TABLE
CREATE TABLE payment_data (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
payment_head VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO payment_data (payment_head, amount) VALUES
('Product Sales', 1000.00),
('Service Revenue', 1500.50),
('Subscription Fees', 500.75);

What exactly is not working with this code? Can you also adjust the tagging?
